# What is the difference between syscat.tabauth and sysibm.systabauth

Tags: db2

What is the difference between these two queries:

```
select * from syscat.tabauth

select * from sysibm.systabauth where tcreator='SYSCAT' and ttname='TABAUTH'
```

Are they same ?

EDIT:
1. select grantee from sysibm.systabauth where tcreator='SYSCAT' and ttname='TABAUTH' and selectauth='Y'

2. select grantee from syscat.tabauth where selectauth='Y'

Would there be any difference in the value of these two queries ??? 
If I change selectauth to 'N' using sysibm.systabauth. Does that reflect in query 2?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that one is a table and the other is a readonly view.
Other differences exist, and they can be version specific.
Different permissions can apply also.

When your target database are always on Linux/Unix/Windows , use SYSCAT schema as IBM tries to keep that unchanged even if the underlying objects change between versions (except where new columns get added ). IBM describes the SYSCAT schema [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008443.html).

The SYSCAT schema contains many views and is relevant for Linux/Unix/Windows versions of Db2-Servers.

The SYSIBM schema contains many tables and is present on both Z/OS and LUW versions of Db2-servers.

So SYSCAT.TABAUTH is only a view on SYSIBM.SYSTABAUTH and you can see the definition of the view in the catalog with a query like this:

```
"select substr(text,1,4096) from syscat.views where viewschema='SYSCAT' and viewname='TABAUTH'"
```

You use GRANT and REVOKE statements to alter the contents of the SYSIBM.TABAUTH table directly, other statements like CREATE/DROP/ALTER table can indirectly change its contents.

Comment: I've added one more thing. Can you answer that as well. Thanks

Comment: It's bad practice to add new questions in edits. Understand that there's only one source of data here, the view is just a select on the real table. IBM encourages LUW applications to only use SYSCAT.